What would be a better for creating a token contract which supports private transactions, Pallier or ElGamal for partial HE?
The token is using additions when it comes to token transfers. Now as far as I know Pallier supports additive homomorphism and ElGamal supports Multiplicative homomorphism. But ElGamal can be additive using exponential Elgamal.
I am confused each of their performance for token transfers(addition) and encryption decryption.
